# Selenium_CaptureEntirePageScreenshot_PHP

Tags: selenium

Want to do a CaptureEntirePageScreenshot while entering the catch block. This runs successfully when the screenshot is saved on the C:// of the remote instance. But want to save on the server instance, so that will be able to add these screenshots to the Hudson Report.

Is saving on remotre machine / server not possible?

its only on that server the HUdson, Bromine are installed.

PHP is used and want solution in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hudsonserverip/pathtosaveinhudsonworkspace as filename to save the screenshot in hudson workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. yes got to know the IP of the server. So should it be like 
$this->selenium->captureEntirePageScreenShot("http://IPaddress/folderstructure"  . "error.png", " ");

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it should be php. In java it will be selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("IPaddress/folderstructure/filename.png"). If the syntax in PHP is captureentirepagescreenshot("path",filename) then yes you are correct.

Comment: Its not path, filename. Its was just a typo in my previous comment with semi-colon ; inbetween. Its just the same method for Java and PHP from the Selenium Class. Tried with and without http ("http://IPaddress/output/images/error.png","") and ("/**.**.**.**/output/images/error.png", "") Both does not work :( Error message: "ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window. The error message is: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"

Comment: what is absolute path and relative path. fopen and fwrite works with the same path i use on server creating a file. But when same path is used for screenshot method, fails :(